# When developing for a tablet PC, how do I determine if the user clicked a mouse or a pen?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablet-pc

How do I check if the user clicked with a mouse or with a pen stylus on a C# control.

For eg. If the user clicks a text box with a pen button then I want an input panel to pop up but if he clicks with a mouse then it shouldn't. So how do I check whether he was using a mouse or a pen?

Edit: Using Windows Forms not WPF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote an article for MSDN that never got published, I guess because Tablet PC development fizzled out by the time I got it to them. But it described how to do this. Long story short, you'll want the GetMessageExtraInfo API. Here's the definitions:

```
// [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
// private static extern uint GetMessageExtraInfo( );

uint extra = GetMessageExtraInfo();
bool isPen = ( ( extra &  0xFFFFFF00 ) == 0xFF515700 );
```

Email me at my first name at Einstein Tech dot net if you want me to send you the article.

Comment: found a link to a MSDN article which explains why the above works, along with other info. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703320.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WPF then there's a whole host of Stylus events. E.g. [UIElement.StylusDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.stylusdown.aspx).

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx) has more details about how stylus and mouse events interact.

If you're not using WPF, why not? :p

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Windows Form :( Any Suggestion for that?

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know too much about this, but I'd guess that if someone is using a stylus, then the mouseEnter, mouseExit (or whatever the equivalent is) events won't ever fire. If one does get fired, then you know that they're using a mouse.

Comment: Those events still fire, it acts like a very fast move of the mouse.