# OpenTK: Distinguish between touch and mouse events in GLControl

Tags: winforms, opentk

GLControl has defined various mouse events (such as `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` etc.). These events are raised even if touch or stylus is used for interaction.
However, I am curious to know if there is a way to distinguish between these events. In other words, I'd like to handle touch events differently than mouse events. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen, you have to determine the event yourself. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758782/when-developing-for-a-tablet-pc-how-do-i-determine-if-the-user-clicked-a-mouse) and [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703320.aspx) helped me.

To summarize, in order to determine what triggered the event, you need to call `GetMessageExtraInfo()` from `user32.dll`. The MSDN article describes how to distinguish between the three inputs based on the bits set on the result of the call. Here's the code I whipped up for this purpose:

```
/// <summary>
/// The sources of the input event that is raised and is generally
/// recognized as mouse events.
/// </summary>
public enum MouseEventSource
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Events raised by the mouse
    /// </summary>
    Mouse,

    /// <summary>
    /// Events raised by a stylus
    /// </summary>
    Pen,

    /// <summary>
    /// Events raised by touching the screen
    /// </summary>
    Touch
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the extra information for the mouse event.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The extra information provided by Windows API</returns>
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern uint GetMessageExtraInfo();

/// <summary>
/// Determines what input device triggered the mouse event.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// A result indicating whether the last mouse event was triggered
/// by a touch, pen or the mouse.
/// </returns>
public static MouseEventSource GetMouseEventSource()
{
    uint extra = GetMessageExtraInfo();
    bool isTouchOrPen = ((extra & 0xFFFFFF00) == 0xFF515700);

    if (!isTouchOrPen)
        return MouseEventSource.Mouse;

    bool isTouch = ((extra & 0x00000080) == 0x00000080);

    return isTouch ? MouseEventSource.Touch : MouseEventSource.Pen;
}
```

For my purposes, I'v overridden `OnMouse*` events in the GLControl class and perform the check using the function above and invoke my custom event handlers accordingly.